# Структуры в языке С

Tags: c

При решение задачи столкнулся с проблемой! Когда программа доходит до второго цикла,она аварийно завершает свою работу.Условие

```
. Описать структуру с именем NOTE, содержащий следующие поля:
• NAME - фамилия, имя;
• TELE - номер телефона;
• BDAY - день рождения (массив из трех чисел). Написать программу, которая выполняет следующие действия:
• ввод с клавиатуры данных в массив BLOCKNOTE, состоящий из восьми элементов типа NOTE; записи должны быть упорядочены по датам дней рождения;
• вывод на экран информации о человеке, номер телефона которого введен с клавиатуры;
• если такого нет, выдать на дисплей соответствующее сообщение.
```

Сам программный код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define day 3
#define count 2
#define notepad 8

struct NOTE {
    char name;
    int tele;
    char bday[day];
} BLOCKNOTE[notepad];

main(void){
    int phone, i, j;
    printf("Enter name,tele,bday:\n");
    for(i = 0; i<count; i++){
        printf("%d)", i+1);
        scanf("%s%d%s", &(BLOCKNOTE[i]).name, &(BLOCKNOTE[i].tele), &(BLOCKNOTE[i].bday));
    }
    printf("enter phone number:");
    scanf("%d", &phone);
    for(j = 0; j<count; j++){
        if(phone==BLOCKNOTE[j].tele)
            printf("Name:\t\t%s\nPhone:\t\t%d\nBday:\t\t%s", BLOCKNOTE[j].name, BLOCKNOTE[j].tele, BLOCKNOTE[j].bday);

        else
            printf("Error! This user not found");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не отображает весь код,сейчас скину скрин

Comment: Не нужно скрин, скиньте код текстом и заключите его в ``

Comment: Какая ошибка, на какой строке?

Comment: Нет ни какой ошибки программа компилируется  нормально,но когда доходит до второго цикла аварийно завершается

Comment: Вам надо в структуре поле `name` объявить как массив символов, а не одиночный символ (ну и с `bday` тоже нехорошо -- раз просят массив из 3-х чисел, так и объявляйте его int bday[3]).

Comment: спасибо,работает

Comment: "Нет ни какой ошибки ... аварийно завершается" - вы сами себе противоречите

Comment: Окошко... Програма завершила свою работу

Comment: @avp, вынесите комментарии в ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: @makintosh, если Вас удовлетворяет ответ, пожалуйста, пометьте его как правильный(галочка рядом с ответом)

Answer (score 5):

Начнем по порядку. Для простоты предположим, что имена имеют ограниченную длину и будем хранить все байты имени в структуре.

```
#define NAME_LEN  20
// символические имена индексов в bday[] (вдруг понадобятся?)
#define DAY   0
#define MONTH 1
#define YEAR  2

struct note_record {
  char name[NAME_LEN + 1]; // строки символов должны заканчиваются нулевым байтом (nil)
  int bday[3];             // dd mm yyyy
  int phone;
};
```

Теперь объявим наш блокнот

```
#define NOTE_SIZE 8
struct note_record note[NOTE_SIZE]; // просто массив структур
```

Организуем простейший ввод данных.

На первый взгляд `scanf("%s%d%d%d%d", note[i].name, &note[i].phone, &note[i].bday[DAY], ...)` это то, что нам нужно.

Однако, мы не можем читать  имена длиннее NAME_LEN и как-то должны сообщить об этом ограничении scanf(). Можно было бы просто написать формат "%20s" (см. man scanf), но все же будет лучше как-то занести в строку формата значение NAME_LEN вместо 20.

*Наверное, самый простой (но не очень наглядный при чтении кода) способ -- это сформировать строку формата:*

```
char format[40]; // этого размера заведомо должно хватить 
sprintf(format, "%%%ds%%d%%d%%d%%d", NAME_LEN);
```

*или можно пойти дальше и сделать ее вот так (по крайней мере в gcc/g++)*

```
char format[snprintf(0, 0, "%%%ds%%d%%d%%d%%d", NAME_LEN) + 1]; 
sprintf(format, "%%%ds%%d%%d%%d%%d", NAME_LEN);
```

*поскольку функция snprintf возвращает количество байт, которое она выведет, независимо от заданного размера поля вывода (мы задаем размер 0).*

*Другой способ вставить значение NAME_LEN в строку формата для scanf() -- использовать возможности препроцессора. Напишем несколько макросов*

```
#define __STR(t) #t
#define _STR(t) __STR(t)
#define NAMELEN _STR(NAME_LEN)
```

*В результате вместо NAMELEN препроцессор будет  подставлять в код значение NAME_LEN в кавычках, т.е. строку. Компилятор соединяет соседние строковые литералы в одну строку, поэтому теперь мы можем записать наш "безопасный" scanf вот так*

```
 n = scanf("%" NAMELEN "s%d%d%d%d", note[i].name, &note[i].phone, &note[i].bday[DAY], ...);
```

*или*

```
 n = scanf(format, note[i].name, &note[i].phone, &note[i].bday[DAY], ...);
```

*для первого из рассмотренных способов формирования формата.*

*Лично мне наиболее симпатичен вот такой вариант*

```
const char *fmt = "%"NAMELEN"s%d%d%d%d";
if ((n = scanf(fmt, note[i].name, ...)) != N_FIELDS) ...
```

Используйте, что больше нравится (подозреваю, что пока Вы остановитесь на
`scanf("%20s%d%d%d%d", note[i].name, ...)`,
но все же будете иметь представление о возможных вариантах кодирования).

К сожалению, мы еще не закончили с вводом.  Если вводимое имя окажется длиннее NAME_LEN, то память мы не попортим (благодаря стараниям по созданию нашего формата), но остаток имени останется во входном потоке, scanf далее попытается прочесть его уже как число (по следующему элементу формата `%d`) и потерпит неудачу.

В таком случае он вернет количество уже успешно введенных полей, чем мы и воспользуемся. Для нас нормальный ввод всех полей, это когда scanf возвращает 5. В случае неудачи я предлагаю просто выбрасывать все введенные байты до символа новой строки и потом повторить попытку ввода.

В результате у Вас должно получиться что-то в таком духе

```
#define SKIP_TO_NL(f) ({int c; while ((c = fgetc(f)) != '\n' && c != EOF); c;})

  const char *fmt = "%"NAMELEN"s%d%d%d%d";
  for (i = 0; i < NOTE_SIZE; i++) 
    if ((n = scanf(fmt, note[i].name, &note[i].phone, 
           &note[i].bday[DAY], &note[i].bday[MONTH], &note[i].bday[YEAR])) != 5) 
      if (n == EOF || SKIP_TO_NL(stdin) == EOF) {
        puts("Bye");
        exit(0);
      } else {
        puts("Input format error, try again");
        --i;
      }
```

Надеюсь, цикл вывода, сортировку, а также диалог с поиском Вы теперь сможете написать сами.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что `SKIP_TO_NL` реализовано на нестандартном диалекте gnuc и к стандартному языку С отношения не имеет.

Comment: @AnT, это верно. Но ведь удобные же расширения у GNU (и для большинства \*nix-ов это родное). Так почему не использовать?